# Duplicate data in ListView when Searching

Tags: android, android-adapter

I'm trying to do search which include images and textview.
So when I search it returns the positive result, but when i go back and search with other value it returns the old return and new result at the same time.
I want my listView not to add old data into it. I need to over write the old data with a new value. here my code :

```
public void onClick(View Kv) {
    Intent moreDetailsIntent = new Intent(MainMenu.this,ListMobileActivity.class);
    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("Prov","KwaZulu-Natal");
    moreDetailsIntent.putExtras(dataBundle);
    startActivity(moreDetailsIntent);                   
});             

B_GP.setOnClickListener(new View .OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View Gv) {
        Intent moreDetailsIntent = new Intent(MainMenu.this,ListMobileActivity.class);
        Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
        dataBundle.putString("Prov","Gauteng");
        moreDetailsIntent.putExtras(dataBundle);
        startActivity(moreDetailsIntent);
    }
});
```

When i click a first buttonKZN it must display all KZN provinces and when click buttonB_GP it must return all GP province. so what it does it just return the old data when i search for the second time, here my listView classess :

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); // Getting the Bundle object that pass from another activity
String SelectedProv = b.getString("Prov");
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ProvinceName",SelectedProv));
Log.d("ProvinceName",SelectedProv);
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://10.0.2.2/php/searchKZN.php", "POST", params);
try{
    JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("PROV");
    for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
        JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);
        String PCity = e.getString("P_City");
        PNames.add(PCity);
        String Pimage = e.getString("Pname");
        PImages.add(Pimage);
    }       
} catch(JSONException e){
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}   
setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, PNames,PImages));
```

So please help me to diplay the correct values according to selected button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this `PNames.clear(), PImages.clear();`

before

```
 for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        

                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                String PCity = e.getString("P_City");
                PNames.add(PCity);
                String Pimage = e.getString("Pname");
                PImages.add(Pimage);
            }
```